# Node server not writing to file?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am running a small twitter stream with npm that is printing tweets to my console.  I would like to write them to disk but my server is not doing this.  Here is my routes.js file:

```
var Twit     = require('twit'), // wrapper on top of twitter api
    dotenv   = require('dotenv'), // used for keys -> get from .env
    fs       = require('fs'); 

module.exports = function(app) {
    dotenv.load();

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:           process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret:        process.env.TWITTER_SECRET_KEY,
    access_token:           process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret:    process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY
});



var middleEast = ['29.4' , '33.7' , '37.7' , '46.1' ]
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', {track: '#ISIS', language: 'en'})
stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {

    if (tweet.geo!=null){
        console.log(tweet.geo.coordinates)
    }

    console.log(tweet.text)
    fs.appendFile("./ISIStweets.json", tweet.text)


})
```

This writes nothing to file.  However, identical code in the same folder, shown below, successfully writes to file.  What gives?

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFile("./ISIStweets.json", "Hello there!\n")
```

Comment: Does the console log the contents of **tweet.text** or any error when you expect the file to be written? Also just a side note, your file has the extension .json but it seems like you're just writing text to it!

Comment: yes, i'm running it right now and here is a sample tweet text:
"@RT_com: MORE: '#ISIS is stronger than ever' - Iraqi govt soldiers http://t.co/015UsesX0f http://t.co/fn2G6oTbWe"

However nothing is written to file.  Also, i've been trying various things, I intend to write the JSON objects to it.

Comment: Also, I've tried several different things such as writing plain text to other file formats but nothing works.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the file? Does it help if you create the file first? I just tried your code on Windows 7 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea.  I Looked at a similar post and I think the npm was installed by root (this code was pulled off a github repo my friend and I wrote), so I ran it with sudo and it worked.  Weird, but thanks, got me on the right track!

Comment: Excellent! I've just posted this as an answer for future reference, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that could've happened here:

Does the console log anything at all? It could be that your tweet stream actually isn't streaming anything.

Do you have permission to write to the `ISIStweets.json` file? If the file already exists, it might be owned by someone other than the user that's running node. If the file doesn't exist, check that you have permission to write in this directory.